# Minimum value of the expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

$$ \frac {(x + \frac1x)^6 - (x^6 + \frac1{x^6}) - 2} {(x + \frac1x)^3 - (x^3 + \frac1{x^3})} $$

I could think of things like AM $\geq$ GM but couldn't see how it would help me to get a maxima. All help would be appreciated.
By the way, for some reason I am getting the correct answer when I substitute for each bracket using AM $\geq$ GM a value of 2.

Comment: Is $x$ assumjed to be positive?

Comment: Yes, $x > 0$ is the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will assume $x >0$. Notice
$$\begin{align} f(x) \stackrel{def}{=} &\; \frac{(x+\frac1x)^6 - (x^6 + \frac{1}{x^6}) - 2}{(x+\frac1x)^3 - (x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3})}
= \frac{(x+\frac1x)^6 - (x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3})^2}{(x+\frac1x)^3 - (x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3})}\\
= &\;\left(x+\frac1x\right)^3 + \left(x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Apply AM $\ge$ GM to the two backets, we have

$$\left(x+\frac1x\right)^3 \ge \left(2\sqrt{x \cdot \frac{1}{x}}\right)^3 = 2^3 = 8
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\left(x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}\right) \ge 2\sqrt{x^3\cdot \frac{1}{x^3}} = 2
$$
This leads to

$$f(x) \ge 8 + 2 = 10\quad\text{ for } x > 0$$

Since this value $10$ is achieved at $x = 1$, we obtain
$$\min_{x > 0} f(x) = 10$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: simplifying the numerator we get $$3\,{\frac { \left( 2\,{x}^{4}+{x}^{2}+2 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{2}}{{x}^{4}}}
$$ and the denominator $$3\,{\frac {{x}^{2}+1}{x}}$$

Comment: This further simplifies to $$\frac{(2x^4 + x^2 + 2) (x^2+1)}{x^3}$$. What would I do next ?

Comment: This tends to $$-\infty$$ for $$x$$ goes to -infinity

Comment: It is $$\frac{(2x^4+x^2+2)(x^2+1)}{x^3}\geq 10$$ the equal sign holds if $$x=1$$

Comment: This inequality above is equivalent to $${\frac { \left( 2\,{x}^{4}+4\,{x}^{3}+9\,{x}^{2}+4\,x+2 \right) 
 \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}}{{x}^{3}}}
\geq 0$$ which is true.

Comment: Well, the answer in the text is 6.

Comment: Then is it a wrong answer!

Comment: Seems so now with everyone proving it to be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle y=x+\frac{1}{x}$.

\begin{align*}
 \frac {(x + \frac1x)^6 - (x^6 + \frac1{x^6}) - 2} {(x + \frac1x)^3 - (x^3 + \frac1{x^3})}& = \frac {(x + \frac1x)^6 - (x^3 + \frac1{x^3})^2 } {(x + \frac1x)^3 - (x^3 + \frac1{x^3})} \\
&=\left(x + \frac1x\right)^3 + \left(x^3 + \frac1{x^3}\right)\\
&=\left(x + \frac1x\right)^3 + \left(x + \frac1x\right)^3-3\left(x + \frac1x\right)\\
&=y(2y^2-3)
\end{align*}

Note that $\displaystyle y\ge2\sqrt{x\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}=2$ and $y(2y^2-3)$ is strictly increasing for $y\ge 2$.

The minimum value is $(2)[2(2)^2-3]=10$.